# Package of Representable functor

Tags: haskell, functor

According to [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors-3.2.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Representable.html), the Representable functor should be in `Data.Functor.Representable` or  in `Data.Functor.Rep` but i can't import it because it's not there.

I'm using `import Data.Functor.Representable` and i also tried `ìmport Data.Functor.Rep` but none of these work. I have ghc version 8.4.3.

Why i can't import it?

Comment: Did you install `representable-functors`, (for example with `cabal install representable-functors`)?

Comment: *representable-functors* (the package to whose docs you link to) was deprecated in favour of [*adjunctions*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions), so you should install *adjunctions* before you can import [`Data.Functor.Rep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html).